# problema con DropDownList

Tags: laravel, blade

hola buenas tengo el error de:

> "Undefined variable: listRegiones"

alguien sabe que es?

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public function verSucursal ()
    {
        //vemos todo lo que esta en la tabla sucursal
        $listSucursal = sucursal::all();
        $listRegiones = regiones::all();
        //retornamos la vista

        return view('sucursales.sucursales')->with(['listSucursal' => $listSucursal],['listRegiones'=>$listRegiones]);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Region</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="listadoRegiones">
                            @foreach ($listRegiones as $listadoR)
                            <option value="{{ $listadoR['id_region'] }}">{{$listadoR['nombre'] }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

PARA ACLARAR, no me encuentra la variable listRegiones, la cual ya etsa declarada, lo eh intentado de varias manera pero aun no me aparece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a pasar a la vista múltiples valores he intentas enviarlos como array asociativo, debería ser de este modo

```
return view('sucursales.sucursales')->with([
        "listSucursal" => $listSucursal,
        "listRegiones" => $listRegiones
     ]);
```

O también usando el método `compact` de este modo

```
return view('sucursales.sucursales', compact("listSucursal", "listRegiones"));
```

Es decir cada pareja de valores separados por una coma

Comment: Entiendo entiendo! Gracias, ahora no me esta reconociendo el listSucursal :(

Comment: que mensaje aparece? @MatiasMuñoz

Comment: Undefined variable: listSucursal

Comment: perdon!!! ya me di cuenta, lo habia declarado en las routes sin querer 2 veces

Comment: Gracias, pero ya lo solucione, gracias por ayudarme y contestarme tan rapido

Comment: Siiii Muchas Gracias, altiro la coloco como solucion

Comment: Si ahora mismo Gracias!